# Angular2 input variable name mapping rule?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am watching a Angular2 tutorial source code here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/AHrB6opLqHDBPkt4KpdT?p=preview

I found that the parent component has

```
[my-prop]="value"
```

but the name 'my-prop' doesn't exist inside the child component.
Instead, the child use the name 'myProp'.

```
@Input() myProp: any;
```

Is there some hidden rule that will map/translate 'map-prop' to 'myProp'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
@Input('my-prop') myProp: any;
```

to able to use like this in the template:

```
<comp [my-prop]="someExpression"></comp>
```

Comment: but the sample doesn't have @Input('my-prop'), it is only @Input(). How can that sample work?

Comment: You're plunkr is very old and beased on an alpha version ;-)

Comment: This doesn't work with beta versions. See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/9c3VEdeBvTmPWXQnBMB3?p=preview. It's the refactored one for beta!

Comment: With the latest beta version, it only works if you specify `my-prop` in the `@Input`...

Comment: ah, thanks for the info. Glad to hear it no longer work in new version.

Answer (score 0):

I did some test with the sample a little.
Just found that system seems auto convert the name (hyphen separated) inside the [] into camel-case variable name for mapping!

so

```
my-prop // can map to [myProp]
my-p-rop // can NOT map to myProp]
my--prop // can NOT map to [myProp], somehow
a-var-name // can map to [aVarName]
```

but for the sake of code quality, it is really not suggested to use this feature.